# Issue styling a wiki link in GitHub Wikis

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I'm currently writing documentation for a school project, and I'm having trouble styling my wiki links with inline code. Below is sort of what I'm attempting to do:

```
`[[wiki link]]` or [[`wiki link`]]
```

Where it styles it [`like this`](https://google.com). I'm not sure if this is just a simple syntax error or if this just isn't supported in Github. If possible, how do I style wiki links like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [this guide](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/), you would have to use the following syntax:

`[wiki link](URL to the wiki link)`

Comment: Sadly, this was the only way that worked with inline code. I ended up just using anchor links and keeping everything on its parent page. Thank you!